# Auto-retry Failed Jobs In Spring XD

Tags: spring-batch, spring-xd

I'm looking for a standard pattern for automatically retrying failed jobs within Spring XD for a configured number of times and after a specified delay. Specifically, I have an HTTP item reader job that is triggered periodically from a cron stream. Occasionally we see the HTTP item reader fail due to network blips so we want the job to automatically try again.

I've tried with a [JobExecutionListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecutionListener.html) which picks up when a job has failed but the tricky bit is actually retrying the failed job. I can do it by triggering a HTTP PUT to the XD admin controller (e.g. `http://xd-server:9393/jobs/executions/2?restart=true`)
which successfully retries the job. However, I want to be able to:

- Specify a delay before retrying
- Have some sort of audit within XD to indicate the job will be retried in X seconds.

Adding the delay can be done within the JobExecutionListener but it involves spinning off a thread with a delay which isnt really traceable from the XD container so it's difficult to see if a job is about the be retried or not.

It appears that you need to have a specific job definition that does delayed job retries for you to be able to get any trace of it from the XD container.

Can anyone suggest a pattern for this?

Answer (score 0):

So here's the solution I went for in the end:

Created a job execution listener

```
public class RestartableBatchJobExecutionListener extends JobExecutionListener {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public final static String JOB_RESTARTER_NAME = "jobRestarter";

    /**
     * A list of valid exceptions that are permissible to restart the job on
     */
    private List<Class<Throwable>> exceptionsToRestartOn = new ArrayList<Class<Throwable>>();

    /**
     * The maximum number of times the job can be re-launched before failing
     */
    private int maxRestartAttempts = 0; 

    /**
     * The amount of time to wait in milliseconds before restarting a job
     */
    private long restartDelayMs = 0;

    /**
     * Map of all the jobs against how many times they have been attempted to restart
     */ 
    private HashMap<Long,Integer> jobInstanceRestartCount = new HashMap<Long,Integer>();

    @Autowired(required=false)
    @Qualifier("aynchJobLauncher")
    JobLauncher aynchJobLauncher;

    @Autowired(required=false)
    @Qualifier("jobRegistry")
    JobLocator jobLocator;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionListener#afterJob(org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution)
     */
    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

        super.afterJob(jobExecution);

        // Check if we can restart if the job has failed
        if( jobExecution.getExitStatus().equals(ExitStatus.FAILED) )
        {
            applyRetryPolicy(jobExecution);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Executes the restart policy if one has been specified
     */
    private void applyRetryPolicy(JobExecution jobExecution)
    {
        String jobName = jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName();
        Long instanceId = jobExecution.getJobInstance().getInstanceId();

        if( exceptionsToRestartOn.size() > 0 && maxRestartAttempts > 0 )
        {
            // Check if the job has failed for a restartable exception
            List<Throwable> failedOnExceptions = jobExecution.getAllFailureExceptions();
            for( Throwable reason : failedOnExceptions )
            {
                if( exceptionsToRestartOn.contains(reason.getClass()) || 
                    exceptionsToRestartOn.contains(reason.getCause().getClass()) )
                {
                    // Get our restart count for this job instance
                    Integer restartCount = jobInstanceRestartCount.get(instanceId);
                    if( restartCount == null )
                    {
                        restartCount = 0;
                    }

                    // Only restart if we haven't reached our limit
                    if( ++restartCount < maxRestartAttempts )
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            reLaunchJob(jobExecution, reason, restartCount);
                            jobInstanceRestartCount.put(instanceId, restartCount);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            String message = "The following error occurred while attempting to re-run job " + jobName + ":" + e.getMessage(); 
                            logger.error(message,e);
                            throw new RuntimeException( message,e);                         
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        logger.error("Failed to successfully execute jobInstanceId {} of job {} after reaching the maximum restart limit of {}. Abandoning job",instanceId,jobName,maxRestartAttempts );                        
                        try
                        {
                            jobExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.ABANDONED);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            throw new RuntimeException( "The following error occurred while attempting to abandon job " + jobName + ":" + e.getMessage(),e);                            
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Re-launches the configured job with the current job execution details
     * @param jobExecution
     * @param reason
     * @throws JobParametersInvalidException 
     * @throws JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException 
     * @throws JobRestartException 
     * @throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException 
     */
    private void reLaunchJob( JobExecution jobExecution, Throwable reason, int restartCount ) throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException
    {
        try
        {
            Job jobRestarter = jobLocator.getJob(JOB_RESTARTER_NAME);
            JobParameters jobParameters =new JobParametersBuilder().
                                        addLong("delay",(long)restartDelayMs).
                                        addLong("jobExecutionId", jobExecution.getId()).
                                        addString("jobName", jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName())
                                        .toJobParameters();

            logger.info("Re-launching job with name {} due to exception {}. Attempt {} of {}", jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName(), reason, restartCount, maxRestartAttempts);

            aynchJobLauncher.run(jobRestarter, jobParameters);
        }
        catch (NoSuchJobException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to find the job restarter with name=" + JOB_RESTARTER_NAME + " in container context",e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the module definition, I add this job listener to the job:

```
<batch:job id="job">
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="jobExecutionListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
    <batch:step id="doReadWriteStuff" >
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter"
                commit-interval="3">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<!-- Specific job execution listener that attempts to restart failed jobs -->
<bean id="jobExecutionListener"
    class="com.mycorp.RestartableBatchJobExecutionListener">
    <property name="maxRestartAttempts" value="3"></property>
    <property name="restartDelayMs" value="60000"></property>
    <property name="exceptionsToRestartOn">
        <list>
            <value>com.mycorp.ExceptionIWantToRestartOn</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- 
Specific job launcher that restarts jobs in a separate thread. This is important as the delayedRestartJob
fails on the HTTP call otherwise!
-->
<bean id="executor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="aynchJobLauncher"
    class="com.mycorp.AsyncJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="executor" />     
</bean>
```

AysncJobLauncher:

```
public class AsyncJobLauncher extends SimpleJobLauncher
{
    @Override
    @Async
    public JobExecution run(final Job job, final JobParameters jobParameters)
            throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException,
            JobParametersInvalidException 
    {
        return super.run(job, jobParameters);
    }
}
```

I then have a separate processor module purely for restarting jobs after a delay (this allows us audit from the spring XD ui or db):

delayedJobRestart.xml:

```
<batch:job id="delayedRestartJob">
    <batch:step id="sleep" next="restartJob">
        <batch:tasklet ref="sleepTasklet" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="restartJob">
        <batch:tasklet ref="jobRestarter" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="sleepTasklet" class="com.mycorp.SleepTasklet" scope="step">
    <property name="delayMs" value="#{jobParameters['delay'] != null ? jobParameters['delay'] : '${delay}'}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobRestarter" class="com.mycorp.HttpRequestTasklet" init-method="init" scope="step">
    <property name="uri" value="http://${xd.admin.ui.host}:${xd.admin.ui.port}/jobs/executions/#{jobParameters['jobExecutionId'] != null ? jobParameters['jobExecutionId'] : '${jobExecutionId}'}?restart=true" />
    <property name="method" value="PUT" />
</bean>
```

delayedJobProperties:

```
# Job execution ID
options.jobExecutionId.type=Long
options.jobExecutionId.description=The job execution ID of the job to be restarted

# Job execution name
options.jobName.type=String
options.jobName.description=The name of the job to be restarted. This is more for monitoring purposes 

# Delay
options.delay.type=Long
options.delay.description=The delay in milliseconds this job will wait until triggering the restart
options.delay.default=10000
```

and accompanying helper beans:

SleepTasklet:

```
public class SleepTasklet implements Tasklet
{
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SleepTasklet.class);

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception
    {
        logger.debug("Pausing current job for {}ms",delayMs);
        Thread.sleep( delayMs );

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    private long delayMs;

    public long getDelayMs()
    {
        return delayMs;
    }

    public void setDelayMs(long delayMs)
    {
        this.delayMs = delayMs;
    }
}
```

HttpRequestTasklet:

```
public class HttpRequestTasklet implements Tasklet
{
    private HttpClient httpClient = null;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpRequestTasklet.class);

    private String uri;

    private String method;

    /**
     * Initialise HTTP connection.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void init() throws Exception 
    {
        // Create client
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setCircularRedirectsAllowed(true)
                .setRedirectsEnabled(true)
                .setExpectContinueEnabled(true)
                .setRelativeRedirectsAllowed(true)
                .build();

        httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                .setMaxConnTotal(1)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception
    {
        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) LOGGER.debug("Attempt HTTP {} from '" + uri + "'...",method);

        HttpUriRequest request = null;
        switch( method.toUpperCase() )
        {
            case "GET":
                request = new HttpGet(uri);
                break;
            case "POST":
                request = new HttpPost(uri);
                break;
            case "PUT":
                request = new HttpPut(uri);
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Http request method " + method + " not supported");
        }

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        // Check response status and, if valid wrap with InputStreamReader

        StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();

        if (status.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) 
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to get data from '" + uri + "': " + status.getReasonPhrase());
        } 

        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) LOGGER.debug("Successfully issued request");

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    public String getUri()
    {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri)
    {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public String getMethod()
    {
        return method;
    }

    public void setMethod(String method)
    {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public HttpClient getHttpClient()
    {
        return httpClient;
    }

    public void setHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }
}
```

And finally when all is built and deployed, create your jobs as a pair (note, the restarter should be defined as "jobRestarter"):

```
job create --name myJob --definition "MyJobModule " --deploy true
job create --name jobRestarter --definition "delayedRestartJob" --deploy true
```

A little convoluted, but it seems to work.